# Django addField ForeignKey during migrations create unusable constraint name

Tags: django, postgresql, constraints, schema, django-migrations

Env: Django 1.8.11 + Postgis

I'm adding some ForeignKeys on a MyModel.
The models pointed are in another schema ("cartography").

```
makemigrations
```

no errors

```
migrate
```

One error. Can't create the constraint because the generated name.
But I'm adding 10 fields, really similar between them. Only one is giving that stupid error.
I can't specify the constraint name anywhere.

```
class myModel(models.Model)
    zps_calculated = models.ForeignKey( Cartography_zps, verbose_name="zps_calcolato", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    zsc_sic_sir_calculated = models.ForeignKey( Cartography_zsc_sic_sir, verbose_name="zsc_sic_sir_calcolato", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    manyothersdata = "xxx"
```

That is the slice of code generated from sqlmigrate (to inspect the code the migration generate).
As you see the name of the constraint is the error.
1 on 10 fields is giving the error

```
CREATE INDEX "segnalazioni_f38ba181" ON "segnalazioni" ("zps_calculated_id");
ALTER TABLE "segnalazioni" ADD CONSTRAINT "se_zps_calculated_id_6844dce0603174b2_fk_"cartography"."zps"_id" FOREIGN KEY ("zps_calculated_id") REFERENCES "cartography"."zps" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
CREATE INDEX "segnalazioni_eb52e53f" ON "segnalazioni" ("zsc_sic_sir_calculated_id");
ALTER TABLE "segnalazioni" ADD CONSTRAINT "cc6ce48808e3a5292779a9787d21e5ad" FOREIGN KEY ("zsc_sic_sir_calculated_id") REFERENCES "cartography"."zsc_sic_sir" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

That is the name giving the error: "se_zps_calculated_id_6844dce0603174b2_fk_"cartography"."zps"_id"
I think should be something like:
"6844dce0603174b2..."

the model NOT giving the error:

```
class Cartography_zsc_sic_sir(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    the_geom = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=23032, blank=True, null=True )
    objects = models.GeoManager()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = '"cartography"."zsc_sic_sir"'
        verbose_name = 'Cartography - zsc_sic_sir'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Cartography - zsc_sic_sir'
        ordering = ["id","slug"]

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nome
```

that is the model giving the error:

```
class Cartography_zps(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=40, blank=True, null=True)
    the_geom = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=23032, blank=True, null=True )
    objects = models.GeoManager()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = '"cartography"."zps"'
        verbose_name = 'Cartography - ZPS'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Cartography - ZPS'
        ordering = ["id","slug"]

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.slug
```

Going further I'm investigating in Django code, backwards.

The

```
 ' %s ADD CONSTRAINT %s FOREIGN KEY (%s) REFERENCES %s (%s)%s;' %
```

is in
/django/db/backends/base/creation.py row 180

using that

```
qn = self.connection.ops.quote_name
```

that SHOULD be the %s constraint name value:

```
qn(truncate_name(r_name, self.connection.ops.max_name_length()))
```

Anyone have an hint to help me?
I'm gonna look what qn does.

https://github.com/django/django/releases/tag/1.8.11

Comment: You've got some very odd things going on in your db_table setting, `'"cartography"."zsc_sic_sir"'`

Comment: I see...
That is the schema+table db table address.

Working flawlessy.

It's not the problem for 9 foreign keys I'm adding.

It's the problem for the 10th

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the attribute name (but I still dunno why):

zps_calculated = models.ForeignKey( Carto...

I renamed it to

zpsasd_calculated = models.ForeignKey( Carto

and the generated constraint name changed to (sqlmigrate):
a326518e5e22b0c2c1251e5bbb331adb

Wow!

Renamed the attribute zpsasd_calculated to zps_calculated, with another migration.

Worked.

Next time I will migrate with custom SQL
https://www.ralphlepore.net/custom-foreign-key-constraints-with-django/